# Can I run an SBT task in a Python script?

Tags: python, sbt

I would like to do something like this:

```
BUILD_APP = True
SKIP_TESTS = False

if not SKIP_TESTS:
    sbt test
```

So whenever I run the script, **sbt** run the tests of the project. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, is as simple as this:

```
if not SKIP_TESTS:
    os.system("sbt test")
```

Comment: using os.system is fine, but, its better to use `popen` from subprocess package